# Selecting last word in screen using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text that is bigger than my screen and i want to select the last word that is showed in my screen and apply a style color red for example. So depending on the resolution of the user the last word wont be the same.

Im trying to use something like counting words but i think im in wrong way.
Using jquery.

```
    function count(){  
  var val   = $.trim($('body').val()),  
      words = val.replace(/\s+/gi, ' ').split(' ').length,
      chars = val.length;
  if(!chars)words=0;

  $('#counter').html('<br>'+words+' words and '+ chars +' characters');
}
count();

$('body').on('input', count);
```

Any help ?

Comment: I would probably modify this script to your liking: https://github.com/layervault/jquery.haircut.js

Comment: what do you want to do after you find the last word?

Comment: Just to clarify - you have a paragraph from which you want the last letter with different style?

Comment: i want to add a style. Just for an exemple. @stackErr .

Comment: @Zword not the last letter, the last word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [See this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fGZ7B/1/)

**JQuery**

```
var s=$('#ele').html();
var spacePos = s.lastIndexOf(' ');
var lastWord = s.substring(spacePos);
var firstWords = s.substring(0,spacePos);
$('#ele').html(''+firstWords+'<span id="diff">'+lastWord+'</span>');
```

In the above fiddle to change styles of the last word edit `#diff{...}` .Also the above code requires the div along with contents to be on the same line.

**HTML**

```
<div id="ele" align="center">hello how are you</div>
```

Comment: Ok, but try to write a text bigger than your screen. Copy paste "lorem ipsum" multiple times and put a overflow:hidden on ur <body>.
It doesnt select the last word on screen. It select last word on our text, but we cant see it cuz its hidden.

Comment: look the test i made with ur fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fGZ7B/4/ see how it doesnt work well.

Comment: I will try to make a fiddle for what you are asking but it will take time

Comment: Sorry @vbotio .I dont think an accurately working solution is possible to get for what you have asked becoz to find a word that is at the last relative to screen is difficult to spot accurately.Check this fiddle that i have tried http://jsfiddle.net/fGZ7B/15/

Comment: thanks. I will try new things and i answer here if i found something :)